# Does macOS use an idle thread for scheduling? If so, how can I monitor its statistics?

Tags: multithreading, macos, operating-system, scheduler

I recently learned that some OS schedulers will use idle threads (one for each core in multi-core processors) during scheduling so that there will always be at least one runnable thread. I was wondering if macOS did something similar? If so, how can I see how much CPU time the idle thread has had? I've tried using the Activity Monitor to see if I could find anything related to this idle thread or scheduler but I can't see to find anything there. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: 'Idle' threads usually loop around a 'halt' instruction, where the CPU  is, well, halted, waiting for an interrupt.  CPU use will therefore be almost zero.

Comment: Is there any way to see how much time the CPU spends in this halted state?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Original poster here, 2 years and 6 months later (now working on the Platform Kernel team at Apple), following up on this question of idle threads in macOS.

So macOS uses the XNU operating system kernel, which it shares with iOS/iPadOS/tvOS/etc., so the real question here is whether or not the XNU scheduler employs idle threads; the answer to that is **yes**. You can actually find the bona fide idle thread code in the open source drop of XNU [here](https://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-7195.81.3/osfmk/kern/sched_prim.c.auto.html) (search for the `idle_thread()` function). As was my hunch back then, there is in fact a *per-processor* idle thread (look [here](https://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-7195.81.3/osfmk/kern/processor.h.auto.html) for the `idle_thread` field of `struct processor`). As far as I can tell, there's no way to use Activity Monitor to tell how much time various processors are spending executing the idle thread.